# require в переменной PHP

Tags: php

Есть файлик. В нем:

```
$content = require(ROOT.'/tpl/login.php');

require(ROOT.'/tpl/main.php');
```

В файле main.php прописано это:

```
echo $content
```

Почему файл **/tpl/login.php** подключается в начале, а не там где надо в main.php? (В браузере запускается site.ru/login.php). Помогите пожалуйста, как сделать правильно?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Почитать про [функцию require](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.require.php), узнать, что она не возвращает результат. Потом почитать про кэширование и функции `ob_`.

Конкретно ваша задача:

```
ob_start();
require ROOT.'/tpl/login.php';
$content = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();

require ROOT.'/tpl/main.php';
```